# What's a good built in data structure to use for jackson json conversion?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

In my ajax response, I want to return a JSON result.

I'm using spring mvc, and I have jackson in my pom.xml already.

Now in my controller's action I have:

```
  @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/someAjaxResponse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String someAjaxResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    }
```

What built in java datastructure/type do you suggest I use so I can then convert it to json using jackson?

I don't want to create a new class for each response type, so I'm looking for a good general  purpose java type for this purpose.

Suggestions?

For converting to json, which method would be best as I know jackson has multiple ways converting objects, like ObjectMapper which I believe you create a single instance of and re-use throughout the entire application?  So does that mean I mark it as final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on your use case. My suggestion is that you create a custom value object that exactly fit your needs, return it and then let Jackson handle the serializaion for you:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/someAjaxResponse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CustomValueObject someAjaxResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

}
```

All that you have to do is to add the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableWebMvc` to your application context, add the Jackson dependencies to your classpath and then the object will be serialized to JSON automatically because you use the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Read more about the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`in the Spring reference manual:

- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable
- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-mapping-json-converter

Note, the returned object can have complex structure. Imagine that you would like to provide person data to the client, then you can return a `Person` object from your controller method:

```
public class Person {
    public String getFirstName() {...}
    public int getAge() {...}
    List<String> getEmailAddresses() {...}
    Address getAddress() {...}
}

public class Address {
    public String getStreet() {...}
    public int getHouseNumber() {...}
    public String getCity() {...}
    public int getZIP() {...}
    public String getState() {...}
}
```

Which may be serialized to:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 42,
    "emailAddresses": [
        "john@doe.com",
        "john.doe@somewhere.com"
    ],
    "address": {
        "street": "First Avenue",
        "houseNumber": 123,
        "city": "Smallville",
        "ZIP": 12345,
        "state": "CA"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is I want to return a String, I guess it is smart enough to not convert to json since my return type is String?  i.e. I put ResponseBody and String as return type, and don't want jackson to get involved.

Comment: Well, when Spring serializes the Person object to JSON data and then writes it to the response body, it will be available as a String to your http clients (provided that they added `application/json` as part of the accept request header).

Comment: I see, so do you think spring looks at the headers to know to return json?

Comment: Yes, Spring checks what are accepted `Content-Type` for request, and uses that to choose conversion. If you returned `plain/text` instead of JSON, String would remain as-is.

Comment: @Blankman @StaxMan The client may specify what media type(s) it can consume by specifying the [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) header and then the server's content negotiation decides what media type that was actually returned in the response and adds the [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header accordingly. Note, clients should also add the `Content-Type` to the request if there is any content in the request body, so that server knows what media type it receives in order to deserialize the content correctly.